# Change specific attribute of href link with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to change one specific attribute of href link.

I have code like this:

```
<div id="123">change id</div>
<a id="link-to-change" href="/something/?id=0&value=15"></a>
```

When i click on `<div>` need to change id in href link to div's id. The href link is dynamic variable.

I tried something like this:

```
$( "#123" ).click(function() {
    var newId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#link-to-change").attr('href', function(){
    return $(this).attr('href').replace(/(id=)[1-9]+/ig, newId );
    });
});
```

I dont know what's wrong and if my regex is correct.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The `))` at the end of the `replace` is a syntax error ?

Comment: you're right, but still not working. I edit )) bug in my post

Comment: Well, here you go -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/3thd4qx4/2/**

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551747/jquery-modify-url-get-parameters

Comment: Thanks,It's work. Can you explain what does "_" mean, in function declaration ?

Comment: it means that the function is going to receive that argument, but he is not going to use it.